# kubectl apply ingress: Unknown field error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

I have ingress as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mongoexpress-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mylocalmongoexpress.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mongoexpress-service
          servicePort: 8081
```

When I run 'kubectl apply -f mongoexpress-ingress.yaml', I get error:

> error: error validating "mongoexpress-ingress.yaml": error validating
> data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend):
> unknown field "serviceName" in
> io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend,
> ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown
> field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend,
> ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0]): missing required
> field "pathType" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.HTTPIngressPath]; if you
> choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with
> --validate=false

Going through online resources, I couldn't find issue in yaml file.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: are you using the right apiversion, inital checks looks like this format was introduced in `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`. In v1 i think you need to define service in the backend then define name and port in side the service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ingress specification [has changed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122) from v1beta1 to v1. Try:

```
...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mylocalmongoexpress.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: mongoexpress-service
            port:
              number: 8081
```

Answer (score 1):

You seems to mix Ingress versions. You declared [networking.k8s.io/v1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ingressbackend-v1-networking-k8s-io), but your block of YAML corresponds to [networking.k8s.io/v1beta1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ingressbackend-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io) - which is no longer available as of `1.22`.

v1beta1

```yaml
- backend:
    serviceName: mongoexpress-service
    servicePort: 8081
```

v1

```yaml
- backend:
    service:
      name: mongoexpress-service
      port:
        number: 8081
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to other answers, you can always use `kubectl explain` in such situations, if you try to do this: `kubectl explain ingress.spec.rules.http.paths.backend.service --api-version=networking.k8s.io/v1` then you'll get:

```
FIELDS:
   name <string> -required-
     Name is the referenced service. The service must exist in the same
     namespace as the Ingress object.

   port <Object>
     Port of the referenced service. A port name or port number is required for
     a IngressServiceBackend.
```

This way you can easily find what fields are available for which resource in which API version.